# Retrieve emails in descending/reverse order using MAILKIT c#

Tags: c#, mailkit, mimekit

I am using `mailkit` currently to retrieve emails. I am using this code :

```
var message = inbox.GetMessage(i);
Emails Email = new Emails;
Email.From = message.From.ToString;
Email.EmailDate = message.Date.ToString;
InboxMails.Add(Email);
```

The problem is, as I am just retrieving the `Date`s, I can see that the emails are retrieved in the reverse order. I mean, `Mailkit` fetches the emails from the last email to the first where it should fetch from first to last. E.g. the last email in my mailbox is from 2/3/2014 and the first one is from 1/1/2018.

Now `Mailkit` loads the last one first and eventually gets to the first one, any way to retrieve in the correct descending order - from the first to the last email?

Also, is there a way to get a `Unique Id` for each message by which I can find / filter the messages?

I tried this :

```
 for (int i = inbox.Count -1; i >= 0; i--)
```

But it doesnt even return a single message

Comment: since mailkit is open source, are you interested in grabbing the source and debugging it?

Comment: should i ?.....

Comment: cant i get this to work ?? cant i retrieve the messages in the order i want to ?

Comment: my idea would be to just get the uids from the mailbox, use linq to reverse order and then loop through and get messages. But I'm sure there are better ways to do it. I'm also new to Mailkit.

Comment: your idea would cost more time....there should be a built in method for this

Comment: getting the uids take no time at all. did it with an account of 44k+ mails in a second. @jstedfast also always uses uids in his code snippets and he wrote Mailkit.

Comment: For example i have a list(of UId)[i mean a list of string filled with UID], how do i get messages with a for each loop ?

Comment: you need an actual `IList<UniqueId>` with `var listUids = client.Inbox.Search(someSearchQuery);`
now you can do your sorting `listUids.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).ToList()`. No retrieve one by one `var mimeMsg = INBOX.GetMessage(id);` using foreach 

the better method though would be `foreach (var item in client.Inbox.Fetch(listUids, MessageSummaryItems.BodyStructure | MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId)) { ... }` but not sure how to do your sorting. if you need a fuller code snipped search stackoverflow for "mysql imap mailkit"

Comment: i actually fixed it ... but thanks anyway